# My Whrilpool refrigerator not working

Tags: ice-maker

My whirlpool side by side is not cold or making ice I have tried to reset the filer and it didn't fix the problem?

Comment: my refrigerator is cold and freezer is not making ice?

Comment: @JereJones. edit your question and the title. do not put updates in comments.  right now your question says that your refrigerator does not work at all.